# Laravel correct permissions

Tags: php, linux, laravel, permissions

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/18341728) wonderful Stackoverflow answer to set up my Laravel's permissions on my Webserver (using the www-data group and user).

When I ssh to my server, I am logged in as `admin` user. I added this user to the www-group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data admin
```

but I am not able to create a file in my Laravel's root folder:

```
➜  laravel git:(production) ✗ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied
➜  laravel git:(production) ✗ whoami
admin
➜  laravel git:(production) ✗ ls -la
total 1164
drwxr-xr-x  17 www-data www-data   4096 Jun 23 13:39 .
```

What do I need to change to be able to have `www-data` permissions as `admin` user?

Not only what do I need to do: What is the best and secure practice?

### my idea:

```
sudo chmod g+w .
```

This works but this is not following the recommendation.

I am running in this issue because I use GitHub actions to deploy my production server and GitHub uses ssh as admin user.

Comment: The file is group readable/executeable, but not group writable

Comment: Read further down in the answer where it shows how to give better permissions (664 and 775) as well the section below that